# Converting the differential of a multi-variable function from Cartesian to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In a homework question I am given function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=\sinh(x^2-4y^3)$ and I am given the point $\left(x_0,y_0\right)=(-2,1)$ in Cartesian coordinates. I am required to find  the values of $A$ and $B$ such that $\text{d}f=A\text{d}r+B\text{d}\theta$ in polar coordinates. 
I have thought of three alternative methods for doing this but I get a different result using each one.
 
At an earlier part of the question I computed the gradient (in Cartesian coordinates) and found it to be $\nabla f(-2,1)=\left[\begin{array}{c|lcr}-4\\-12\end{array}\right]$.

My first approach was that as far as I know the following equality holds:
$$\text{d}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\text{d}r+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\text{d}\theta$$ so $A$ should be equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ and $B$ should be  equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta }$.   Doing a couple of calculations I found that at the point $(-2,1)$ the unit polar vectors are :
$$\hat{r}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\begin{matrix}-2\\1\end{matrix}\right];\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\end{matrix}\right]$$
so the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $r$ should just be the dot product of the Cartesian gradient and the unit vector $\hat{r}$:
$$f_r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\nabla f(-2,1)\cdot\left[\begin{matrix}-2\\1\end{matrix}\right]=-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}=A$$
and likewise with the partial derivative with respect to $\theta$:
$$f_\theta=-\frac{28}{\sqrt{5}}=B$$

However, to verify my answer I also tried doing the following:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\right)^{-1}$$
From the equation $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ I get $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Evaluating this at my point gives me $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ so all in all I get:
$$f_r=-10\sqrt{5}=A$$
I did notice that if I had plugged in $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}$ themselves I would have got the same answer as in the previous method but I have no idea why.

The third method I tried is as follows:
I have: 
$$dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}d\theta$$ 
$$dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}d\theta$$
From the equations $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ I get:
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos{\theta}$$ 
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}=-r\sin{\theta}$$ 
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\sin{\theta}$$
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}=r\cos{\theta}$$
And I know that at my point there obtains:
$$r\cos{\theta}=-2 \Rightarrow \cos{\theta}=-\frac{2}{r}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$r\sin{\theta}=1 \Rightarrow \sin{\theta}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$
And so:
$$df=-4dx-12dy=-4\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}dr-d\theta\right)-12\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}dr-2d\theta\right)=-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}dr+28d\theta$$
So here I  basically got the same answer for $A$ as with the first method but a different, albeit similar, answer for $B$. It would be great if someone can explain to me which solution (if any) is correct and why is it correct and the others not.

Edit: 
I just noticed that using the first method I mistakenly found $-\hat{\theta}$ instead of $\hat{\theta}$ which should give me the answer $B=\frac{28}{\sqrt{5}}$ and I'm guessing that this is the correct solution (my intuition behind it is the strongest at least). So my question essentially breaks down to this: why in using the third method I get the un-normalized result for $f_\theta$ and why plugging in $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}$ instead of their inverses in the second method would have given me the same result as in the first method?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that you’re just meant to use the chain rule here.

Comment: In the third method what I did is basically using the chain rule. What I don't understand is why the chain rule gives me the un-normalized result for the partial derivative of f with respect to theta compared to what I get using the gradient method.

Answer (score 1):

Your third answer is the correct one. There are errors in your other two methods.

In the first, the unit vector $\ \hat{\theta}\ $ needs to be in the direction of *increasing* $\ \theta\ $—that is, $\ \hat{\theta}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}\ $, the negative of what you took it to be, and to get the partial derivative $\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\ $ you need to take the dot product of $\ \nabla f\ $ with $\ r\hat{\theta}\ $, not with $\ \hat{\theta}\ $, as you seem to have done.

The mistake in your second method is the assumption that $\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}^{-1}\ $ and $\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}^{-1}\ $, which is incorrect.  Because the transformation from  Cartesian to polar coordinates is *two*-dimensional, the relation between these partial derivatives is given by a matrix equation
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}}=\pmatrix{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\\ \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}}^{-1}\ .
$$

Comment: I only partially understand why I should take the dot product of the gradient with $r \theta$ instead of just $\theta$. I do understand that a change in angle will cause a greater change in arc length the further you are from the origin, but shouldn't you normalize this vector in order to get the directional derivative with respect to a unit vector in the direction of $\theta$?

Comment: It's just the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\\
&=-r\sin\theta \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+r\cos\theta \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\
&=r\nabla f\cdot\hat\theta\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ \hat{\theta}$ is the unit vector $\ (-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)\ $.

Comment: One further note: You're right that the *directional derivative* of $\ f\ $ in the direction $\ \hat{\theta}\ $ is $\ \nabla f\cdot\hat{\theta}\ $, but $\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\ $ *isn't* that directional derivative.